# Adding a CAP/MAX to a If statement calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have a formula to calculate commission:

```
=IF(D3>=4,D4*0.05,IF(D3>=2,D4*0.03,IF(D3>=1,D4*0.02,0))).
```

I need to add a way to cap/max the calculation.

The max commission that an individual can make is $150 per the number in D3.

Comment: What do you mean by "per the number in D3"? Please be more specific about what you want the formula to do. Examples would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MIN`:

```
=MIN(150*D3,IF(D3>=4,D4*0.05,IF(D3>=2,D4*0.03,IF(D3>=1,D4*0.02,0))))
```

The MIN function retrieves the smallest value from a set of data, in this case it shows the smallest among (150*D3) and the result of the formula,

Comment: That works if i have a count of 1, in D3

Comment: @SDArnold99 My bad!!!. I corrected the formula.

Comment: I just realized that the formula works for when the calculated amounts are all above 150 or all below 150

Comment: When one of the calculations, calculates above 150 and one below, it does gives me the result of 300 instead of 150 for one item and the calculated amount for the other item